# @nn.compact usage in FLAX

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, flax

What is the use of @nn.compact in FLAX?

```
class Net(nn.Module):

@nn.compact
def __call__(self, x):
    self.n = 1
    return x
```

The same can be done by using :

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def setup(self):
    self.n = 1
def __call__(self, x):
    return x
```

What is the use of the decorative @nn.compact using explicitly in the code?